# In-app purchase cannot connect to iTunes Store

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform, in-app-purchase

In my app, I wanna an in-app purchase for removing banner add, and I wrote this code:

```
 if adBannerView != nil{
    let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()

        if userDefaults.boolForKey("proUser") {
        self.adBannerView?.hidden = true
        }

    } else {
    self.adBannerView?.hidden = true
    }

    self.canDisplayBannerAds = true
    self.adBannerView?.delegate = self
    self.adBannerView?.hidden = true
}

func bannerViewWillLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {

}

func bannerViewDidLoadAd(banner: ADBannerView!) {
     self.adBannerView?.hidden = false
}

func bannerViewActionDidFinish(banner: ADBannerView!) {

}

func bannerViewActionShouldBegin(banner: ADBannerView!, willLeaveApplication willLeave: Bool) -> Bool {
    return true
}

func bannerView(banner: ADBannerView!, didFailToReceiveAdWithError error: NSError!) {
    self.adBannerView?.hidden = true
}
```

And, this is my codes for "no-ads" button

```
@IBAction func noAds(sender: AnyObject) {
    PFPurchase.buyProduct("com.**.***", block: { (error:NSError?) -> Void in
        if error != nil {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error", message: error?.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
            alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default, handler: nil))
            self.presentViewController(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)           
        }
   })
}
```

But, when I run my app on simulator, it gives me an alert window, first it says "Do you want to purchase no ad for $0.99?", they I press "buy", it waits a while, pop out an alert window, says "Cannot connect to iTunes Store", I searched reason for that, some webpage says "You might wrote some code wrong", so can anyone help me that something wrong with those codes?

Plus, this is my codes in AppDelegate:

```
  func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
   Parse.enableLocalDatastore()

    Parse.setApplicationId("****************************",
        clientKey: "****************************")

    PFAnalytics.trackAppOpenedWithLaunchOptions(launchOptions)

    PFPurchase.addObserverForProduct("com.**.***", block: { (trasition:SKPaymentTransaction!) -> Void in
        let userDefaults = NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults()
        userDefaults.setBool(true, forKey: "proUser")
        userDefaults.synchronize()
    })
    return true
}
```

I use Parse to enable In-App purchase.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to test in-app purchases (IAP) in the simulator as far as I know. To test them you need to use a real device and use an iTunes account that has been specifically setup as a test user.

Apple has more details here https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/iTunesConnectInAppPurchase_Guide/Chapters/TestingInAppPurchases.html

Comment: It looks correct to me but I haven't used Parse before.